# How to open git branch select in vscode by keyboard?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

[image]

In VSCode, there a git branch select option in the left-bottom, Is there any way to activate this by keyboard rather than click by a mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the

`Git: Checkout to...` command.

It is unbound by default.  For example:

```
{
  "key": "alt+c",
  "command": "git.checkout"
}
```